# cloudbuild.yaml create a sql instance

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-build

Hi I am new to the GCP world and am creating my first cloudbuild.yaml file.

I haven't found an example of how to create a cloud sql instance(Postgres or MySQL), is this not supported?

it's not listed in the [cloud-builders-community on GitHub](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-builders-community).

Anything to point me in the right direction would be a big help.

I have this below and don't know if it is the correct or best way to do this:

```
        # # steps:
    # # # Create Cloud SQL Instance
    # # - name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud
    # #   id: 'create_cloud_sql_instance'
    # #   entrypoint: "bash"
    # #   args: 
    # #     - '-c' # pass what follows as a command to bash
    # #     - |
    # #       gcloud sql instances create $_INSTANCE_NAME --database-version=POSTGRES_11 \
    # #        --cpu=$_NUMBER_CPUS --memory=$_MEMORY_SIZE \
    # #        --region=[$_REGION] 
    # #   waitFor: ["-"]
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please just a question to help you, is this instance creation is really linked with a build ? [Deployment manager](https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/docs/) is the solution for infrastructure as a code. Maybe it could also help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right track, but you don't need to change the entrypoint to be `bash` and then execute the `gcloud` command, as the `gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud` image already has `gcloud` as the entrypoint.

Doing this works:

```
steps:
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
  args: ["sql", "instances", "create", "$_INSTANCE_NAME", "--database-version=POSTGRES_11", "--region=$_REGION"]
```

Also you don't need the `waitFor` tag for the step either, if you are not concerned about concurrent/consecutive build steps.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to reply. This now works for me. Really appreciate it 